# When you change routes, meta does not change, although title changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I use Nuxt / SSR. When you change routes, description, og:title, og:description does not change, although title changes.

Each component has a code like this:

```js
head() {
  return {
    content: this.page.title
    meta: [{
        hid: 'description',
        name: 'description',
        content: this.page.description
      },
      {
        hid: 'og:title',
        property: 'og:title',
        content: this.page.title
      },
      {
        hid: 'og:description',
        property: 'og:description',
        content: this.page.description
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Where *this.page* - is the data obtained from **vuex**, which is taken from the API at *middleware* level

Comment: Where are `this.page` stored? `data()`?

Comment: Meta is only really needed on initial render, so this might be intentional.

Comment: Do you use class-components in your project?

Comment: @kissu updated. this.page - is the data obtained from vuex, which is taken from the API at middleware level

Comment: @florian-pallas I thought so too. But I want to know 100% that it's true

Comment: @eduardo Nope, it's just simple components